# Elasticsearch check if subset of word exists

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm trying to search a word that is a subset of a given word. *For example*, if I search the word *"localhost.testsite.com"*, I should get results that have *"testsite.com"*. I know we can do vice-versa with wildcards, but it's hard to find an example with my requirement.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
GET domains/_search
{
  "from": 0," size": 25,
    "query": 
    {
      "bool": 
      {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "domain": "localhost.testsite.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

But this matches the whole word. Does someone know how to query so that it checks for subsets like *"testsite.com"*?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom analyzer which uses a [char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) to replace the `.` with the `space`.

Below is the setting to create the above analyzer. You can use [analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API to verify this.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_dots"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_dots": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ". => \\u0020"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This analyzer will create below tokens for the field containing `testsite.com`

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "testsite",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "com",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you need to use the `match` query on the same field, as match query is analyzed and uses the same analyzer, so for search text `localhost.testsite.com` below tokens would be generated.

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "localhost",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "testsite",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 18,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "com",
            "start_offset": 19,
            "end_offset": 22,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Now as your document contains both `testsite` and `com` tokens, so it will come in the search result.

Let me know if you need any help in understanding this.

**EDIT:**- Some links for understanding the analysis process https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Comment: Thanks Amit. But I am running the query in a python lambda. So wouldn't prefer complicating it. Isn't there another way?

Comment: @SSen, Sorry dude but there is no inbuilt analyzer to address your issue.

Comment: Ok. Can the custom analyzer be created on an existing index?

Comment: yes, but  still you need to re-index the whole data, as its a breaking change and re-indexing will only bring the latest tokens based on new analyzer  in the index.

Comment: @SSen , let me know if you were able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you let me know if re-indexing the whole data would mean all existing records get removed?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I would definitely upvote your answer because it's one way of doing it. But I need to be able to work on an existing index without losing any of the data in it. So I had to handle it from a lambda side and it works.

Comment: @SSen, could you please explain how you handle it using lambda, and did you still change the analyzer ? it would be interesting to know this , may be you can write answer explaining this, so that we can also learn from you :-)

Comment: I didn't make any change to the analyzer because I'm working on an existing index. I fetched all domains that I had to consider and then checked if any domain exists in the domain I pass. Might not be the best approach but can't think of anything better.

Comment: @SSen, this is surely a way but not the best and fast, and you are not using ES for search :).. I would suggest you create another field and add this analyzer and using this you can start indexing the new data as its incremental change.. this way atleasr new doc will work and whenever there is old document updated that document will also have latest token and would be including in your search result, other you can refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html for reindexing without downtime and its pretty fast.